# Extend desktop to dual monitors with motherboard gpu

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, motherboard

I have a Windows 7.

I can't use my Nvidia card any more, and I can't afford to replace it yet so i wanted to use my onboard GPU with dual monitors.

My motherboard has a HDMI and DVI port. I plugged both my regular display and my graphic tablet ( a poor man's wacom cintiq ) and they are both recognized but will only mirror / clone.

My [manual](https://download.msi.com/archive/mnu_exe/M7816v1.0_EURO.zip) says: "This platform supports dual-display or triple-display function by integrated graphics output ports."

[image: Screenshot of manual]

How to extend my desktop?

For info, this is my motherboard and CPU :

[MSI B85-G43 Specs](https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/B85-G43/Specification)

[Intel core I5 4440](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/75038/intel-core-i5-4440-processor-6m-cache-up-to-3-30-ghz.html?wapkw=intel%20core%20i5%204440)

Thanks everyone in advance, if anyone has a solution you would do a broke ass artist a solid.

Comment: Please specify the exact model/type of your CPU. It is important to be able to answer this question. And please don't link to a French-only web-site... The vast majority of people here don't speak French.

Comment: So very sorry for the french link, i edited it as well as the CPU with a link to the intel website.

Comment: Add to your question: What OS? Add an OS tag.

Comment: I did thank you .

Comment: What you describe sounds like a hardware limitation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the specifications your motherboard and CPU seem to support up to 3 monitors using the VGA, DVD-D and HDMI outputs.

Make sure you have removed the Nvidia card from the system. Don't leave it in if you don't want to use it.

Check the BIOS settings:
Set both the gfx memory settings to Maximum values and you may have to change the IGP multi-monitor support setting to either disabled or enabled.
(And updating the Bios to the latest version may also help.)

Last, but not least: Install the latest Intel motherboard chipset and integrated graphics drivers. (Not the ones from the MSI website. Get fresh ones from  Intel.)
It is very well possible that these must be updated or refreshed in order to enable full functionality.

Comment: oh my god than you so much Tonny, it worked ! i didn't think about the integrated graphic drivers .... I'm such a noob. Thank you so much.

Comment: It is easily overlooked. When you have a separate GFX card in the system the Windows default driver that gets loaded for the IGP in the CPU is good enough. But you need the full driver package to be able to use it fully.